# Backpropagation (matrixis not aligned)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

Well, the problem is with delta1, I've checked over math couple times, it seems good to me, everything should be correct with delta2, but it doesn't match with W2 transposed, here is backpropagation:

```
def backward(self, X, Y):
    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    delta2 = -(Y - self.yHat) * self.deriv_sigmoid(self.a2)
    dJdW2 = np.dot(self.a2.T, delta2)
    delta1 = np.dot(delta2, self.W2.T)*self.deriv_sigmoid(self.a1)
    dJdW1 = np.dot(X.T, delta1)
    return dJdW1, dJdW2
```

here is forward propagation:

```
def forward(self, X):
    self.X = X
    self.a1 = np.dot(self.W1, X)
    self.Z1 = self.sigmoid(self.a1)
    self.a2 = np.dot(self.W2, self.Z1)
    self.yHat = self.sigmoid(self.a2)
    return self.yHat
```

And here is file from witch I call it:

```
NN = nn.Neural_Network(2, 3, 1)
X = [[1],[1],]
Y = [[1],]
yHat = NN.forward(X)
dJdW1, dJdW2 = NN.backward(X, Y)
```

I've tried checking placings in np.dot(), but it seems to be correct, and here is full code: https://hastebin.com/ikijahecaz.py

Comment: Well, I found my problem, in backward function:                                                    delta2 = -(Y - self.yHat) * self.deriv_sigmoid(self.a2), it should be:         delta2 = -(Y - self.yHat) * self.deriv_sigmoid(self.Z1)